# My Gmail account suspended

Tags: gmail

I can't access my Gmail account. When entering my email address, a window pops-up telling me that this account has recently been suspended. There is a button "Next" to help me solve the problem, but when I click on it, I get an apology saying that there is no solution to solve this problem.
Could this have to do with cookies? or hackers?
When I want to open a new account under this same address, I am told that this account already exists, but when I want to access it, I am told that it has been deleted.

Comment: Hi and welcome. If the email address in your question is your real address, then would you please change it asap for the sake of your privacy as well as spammers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you tried logging from a newly opened private/incognito window, or clearing the cookies before trying to do it? Maybe something remained there and confuses the system.
   (Unlikely to help, but would be something too simple to miss just in case.)
2. If so and things don't change, you could perhaps try getting in touch with Google in another way to reactivate your account.
   (I assume "all" of your account, including YouTube etc. is disabled now.)
   For this you could try navigating to https://accounts.google.com first of all and see what your options are.
   You should expect a page similar to the one here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/40695
   (see below as well)

[image]